# What is the background to this site? How was it made? Is it Space?

Tags: discussion, design

I would really like to know how the background on this site was made, was it a picture, or a drawing, or photoshop?

Comment: The person who designed the site layout laid out some of their thought process here: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/976/design-for-science-fiction-fantasy

Comment: possible duplicate of [New Design Launched](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/989/new-design-launched)

Answer (score 8):

#### Let me lead with the fact I did not design the background but I am a graphic designer of online images for CSS backgrounds. With that said, the background is not a natural starfield as would be seen in space and instead would appear to be a regular grid of images which can imitate a star field.

- If you look closely you can see the reappearance of artistic elements in the star field at regular intervals.

[image]

- As for the upper banner region, each of the elements was found separately and likely layered and arranged in Adobe Photoshop or another corresponding graphic art manipulation program.
- I know the art elements were available in the general public because I emulated the design used here on my own website by finding said graphic elements and layering them in Adobe Photoshop.

Comment: Thank you so much! you have answered my question in a VERY detailed way, you are AMAZING! Thank you. You knew exactly what I meant! Thank you soooo much!

Comment: With "reappearance of artistic elements", you mean that the background consists of repeating panes, surely. I can agree with that, but that doesn't mean each pane was drawn by hand; each could easily have been a photo.

Comment: Whether they are actually a space image or not is irrelevant. It IS just a tiny panel repeated across the landscape of the page. I believe it is the information about the use of the panel the OP is asking about. It could be space, it could be a photo, it could be a construction in Photoshop. I could do all three in about the same amount of time.

Comment: @Thaddeus The image makes it look like there's a hole in your answer. It's a really cool effect.

Comment: Poking through the site's CSS, it's a 255x255 pixel image, tiled to infinity. The tile is [here](http://cdn.sstatic.net/scifimeta/img/bg-site.jpg?v=f106e2447e62)